# What is a typical response time for a wired controller?

Tags: controllers

What is a typical response time for a wired controller? I mean the time between you press a button and a PC game can recognise it?
To be specific let's take Xbox One controller.

Is it comparable to human reaction time (0.1-0.2 sec) or significantly smaller?

*I fail to google that because the Internet is full of complains about random controller lags, which I'm not interested in here.*

Comment: It's going to be slightly slow than the speed of the signal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [Kotaku.com](https://www.kotaku.com.au/2013/08/how-the-xbox-one-controller-has-changed/)

> The new proprietary protocol—to be clear, it's not WiFi nor Bluetooth,
>   which Alam said was too slow for their needs—should reduce
>   controller-to-console latency by 20% compared to the old 360
>   connection. How fast? Alam says that the time from button press on an
>   Xbox One controller to the console receiving the signal should be **9**
>   **milliseconds**. He believes that is effectively the same as with a wired
>   controller

If the latency has been reduced by 20%, it would imply that Xbox 360 response times were around 11 ms.

This is significantly shorter than the 100-200 ms human response time you asked about. A single frame at 60 fps is 16 ms long, which is why on most games controller inputs appear to be mirrored in game instantly as the response occurs in less than one frame.

Answer (score -1):

This is a bit of an old thread, but here's a link to a great study by a rocket league player over on reddit. https://www.reddit.com/r/RocketLeague/comments/8wvf9u/controller_input_lag_comparison_more_info_in_the/

The gist of it is that the general response times for controllers on the PC is ~3 - 15 ms. It's there, but not particularly noticable.

Comment: Whilst the brief summary is good this would be better if you [edit]ed in some of the relevant content from the link in case it goes dead.

Answer (score -3):

Actual input delay tests show PS4 and Xbox One both have an input delay of about 90 ms. Look up Video Game Input Lag Database.